# Was in IT, but now re-positioned to work outside of IT - how to deal with it?

Tags: new-job

so I've been with the company for about 4 years.  I have a Computer Engineering degree and always excelled working in IT.  Just recently there was a shift in the organization that led to me being re-positioned to a rotational role (temporary - 1.5 years) outside of IT, more in business a business role. I believe after the 1.5 years, I would then be okay to transfer back to IT - really not knowing where that would be at the moment.

At first when my higher ups told me about the position, I told them that I wasn't interested and that my strong suit is in IT - so as I compromise they split the role with IT and Business responsibilities and was basically forced in taking the role.

I do feel very much outside my comfort zone and feel like I can't excel as much as if I was working in IT.  I don't feel like myself and feel overwhelmed with all the work that is thrown at me.  I can't seem to keep up with the IT responsibilities (even though I can do them with no problem) because I'm also responsible with the other business responsibilities.  So I'm basically doing two different roles as a one person.

How would you handle this role?  Who would you talk to and what would you say? Would you start looking for a new job and take a risk of reduced compensation?  Note that the compensation here is very good and competitive.

Comment: "*How would you handle this role?*" Questions like this are off-topic here because they are meaningless as each person's priorities are different. What do **you** want to do? Transition back to pure IT work? Reduce your workload? Find a new job?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Mind you alot of people don't want to shine or get bigger and better duties. If someone put me in a role outside of what I learned and what they hired me to do, well first of all that would be illegal in germany but if they could I would quit immideatly.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere And I provided my take on it :)

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your company is having problems aligning IT with the business objectives. A common strategy is to rotate employees so people get a bigger picture of the business. The goal is either to make you a better at IT, or to make the revenue generating businesses better at leveraging IT. A year and a half is certainly longer than the normal, and makes me think they're trying to extend IT into the business. One outcome may be to break up a centralized IT into business-specific IT departments. You may have been selected because you have a reputation for effective solutions, but everyone may follow.

I would embrace this. Expectations will be low. You will be astounded at how backward some very smart people are in their use of technology. A simple Excel tip might save someone days of work a month. You will make better IT decisions. You'll see where some of the "random" requirements come from, and why some deadlines are more important than others. You'll have insights beyond your peers.

Putting yourself outside your comfort zone is important for your career. The strong-arm tactics being employed here, and the language in your post, leads me to believe your managers feel the same.  On an important related note--IT is not a good long-term investment. Irreversible trends in devops and SaaS are contracting IT budgets, and the future is bleak. You will wind down your career in the margins, handling less and less valuable responsibilities.

Answer (score 2):

1.5 years is a long time to be doing a job you don't like and don't want to make a focus of. You have already changed roles so it's a bit late to refuse so you really only have a couple of options.

Soldier on through it and learn the business role as well as you can, this is important because it will impact on your reviews.

or

Soldier on, and quietly start looking for another job

or

Lastly, take it up with your manager that it's not working out for you. This may get you nowhere but at least you'll know more. Some workplaces want multi-skilled employees and it's important to become multi-skilled if you want to advance in them. So ask yourself if you see yourself still working there in 5 years time or not. If not, then start looking around for somewhere which will pay you to focus on your strength.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little bit late, as you already have started with the new role, but those are my two cents:

- See it as a promotion. Normally you will be required to do some business topics at some point in your career. If your boss did not offer you an appropriate compensation for your new tasks, renegotiate it!
- Find a new job. If you don't want to do those new tasks, hand in your notice and run.
- Try to resolve the situation together with your manager. Maybe some training is in order for you. Ask him what he can do for you.
- Hand off some tasks to colleagues if you feel overwhelmed.